# CheckBoxEdit into WPF grid (DevExp)

Tags: wpf, checkbox, grid, devexpress

Hello i put TextBox Column into WPF grid like this:

```
DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.GridColumn col = new GridColumn();
col.FieldName = dr["FieldName"].ToString();
col.Header = dr["Caption"].ToString();

//Gets or sets the name of the column
col.Name = "c"+ dr["FieldID"].ToString();

Grid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Does anyone knows how to add a CheckBox to this WPF grid (Cell should look like some checkbox)..? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use EditSettings property of the GridColumn class; you can initialize it with TextEditSettings, CheckEditSettings, ComboBoxEditSettings, DateEditSettings settings classes for different editor types. The one you need for check box is CheckEditSettings.

Comment: Ok, You are right. Thanks. I have posted 3 questions to get correct answer.